120 in vertical longer but flat SWR on 27.185 MHz
I recently put a antenna bracket adapter onto a 4 ft piece of steel pipe attached to a tree (6 ft high) with a ratchet strap.
One radial, about 10 ft long, is going at a downwards angle to a metal cage on the ground.  It's a 10 ft long stick of all thread that is the vertical radiating element.
My SWR is 1.1 at 27.185 MHz.
It should be resonant at a lower frequency.  Maybe 26 MHz or so. It roughly 17 in longer than it should be.
Anyone able to explain how this happens?


One radial, about 10 ft long, is going at a downwards angle to a metal cage on the ground.

The radial length influences the frequency at which the SWR drops to the minimum, because radials are reactive (they change the feedpoint impedance vs frequency characteristics).
Furthermore, your radial seems to be resting on a metal cage on the ground. This makes the end of the radial connected to the ground (lossy dielectric) via a capacitor if you were to make an equivalent circuit model. This can bring the minimum SWR frequency down.
Ground is a lossy material. For effective use of the RF power from the transmitter, I recommend carefully assessing your radial placement. Unless there is a good reason, I would decouple your radial from the ground.

You being less than 4 % off your expected frequency in an environment where there is stell of unknown conductivity, magnetic properties, a tree of unknown conductivity, threaded rod with unknown surface properties involved, over ground that might or might not be a very good ground plane:
That's pretty good! You're not building this antenna using perfectly straight, perfectly constructed elements on perfectly isolated masts on an ideal ground plane.
So, what happens here is that when people write down formulas for the optimal frequency of operation for an antenna, they must make simplifications – partially because they literally can't know everything about the environment the antenna will be deployed in, and partially because otherwise the formula becomes too complex to be calculateable.
In your case, that'd honestly not even be a problem! Your antenna will not be a terrible antenna 1 MHz to 2 MHz away from it's peak efficiency.
